# How to create a virtual host in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost, lamp, ubuntu-13.10

I am using ubuntu 13.10 OS and LAMP, Apache 2.4.

I would like to create a virtual host on apache. I tried some code, but it didn't work.

The following modifications are made. but it's not working.

First I changed `HostnameLookups off` to `HostnameLookups on` on `etc\apache2\apache2.conf` file. Then I added the below code,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName local.scholarships.theiet.in
DocumentRoot /home/www/my_project/public_html
<Directory path_to_code_base/public>
    Options -Indexes
    Require all granted
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After restart apache I ran `http://localhost/` . The site is not loaded.

How can I load my site when running `http://localhost/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an another way of create a **virtual host in ubuntu 13.10**

Below example shows how to create a virtual host,

**Step 1**: create a PHP project named `site1.com` on `/home/user/www/`

**Step 2**: Change `HostnameLookups off` to `HostnameLookups on` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

**Step 3**: Create a config file named `site1.com.conf` on `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

Add this code to `site1.com.conf`,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site1.com
ServerAlias www.site1.com
ServerAdmin info@site1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory "/var/www/site1.com">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 4**: Then add `127.0.0.1 site1.com` to `/etc/hosts.txt`

**Step 5**: Open terminal and run the commands,

```
sudo a2ensite site1.com

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

**Step 6**: Open browser and run `http://site1.com/`

Try this

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can create virtural host on Apache/Ubuntu:

**My 000-default.conf file:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/php/frbit/l4blog/public/
    <Directory /var/www/php/frbit/l4blog/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ServerName l4blog
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that I created **ServerName**, which is the name of my new host.

And you can add new host name in /etc/hosts file like this:

```
127.0.0.1   your_host_name
```

In order not to type long url e.g. instead of

```
http://localhost/path/directory/file/...
```

You can just enter **your_host_name** in the address bar:

```
your_host_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration files filenames in the sites-available directory must now end in ".conf", so in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ add your .conf file, named in the style of example.com.conf; model it on the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin you@example.com
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
    require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example.com.error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example.com.access.log combined    
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable it in apache with:

```
$ sudo a2ensite example.com
```

(If you need to disable it later use $sudo a2dissite example.com)

You might also need to add a line to your /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

Don't forget that although you've added the site to apache with a2ensite, you will also need to restart apache.

Comment: getting error while restarting apache "sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin"

Comment: That is something totally different - above you have two high quality answers related to your virtual host question. If you have more issues, create new post.

Comment: But to be more helpful, I think that issue (re sudo) has been addressed on the askubuntu site at http://askubuntu.com/questions/170216/sudo-doesnt-work :-)